# Icon flashing when clicked. Is it possible to stop this?

Tags: html, css, gatsby

I have set up a sidebar that upon hovering, reveals the menu item name. The menu item also goes green when the user goes on that particular page.

The problem is that upon clicking the menu item, the icon flashes for a split second (see below gif). I would like to stop this from happening and just have the text turn green with no flash of the icon.

I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions as to how I could make this stop happening?

[image]

Im using Gatsby.js (very similar to React.js). Below is a simplified version of my code:

My JS:

```
import React from "react"
import {
  TiHomeOutline,
  TiSocialSkypeOutline,
  TiSocialLinkedin,
  TiSocialFacebook,
} from "react-icons/ti"
import { FiSettings, FiUser, FiMail } from "react-icons/fi"
import { IoIosCode } from "react-icons/io"
import { FaWhatsapp } from "react-icons/fa"

import { Link } from "gatsby"
import "./sidebar.css"
const Sidebar = props => (
  <div className="sidebar">
    <div>
      <div className="site_title">
        <Link to="/">
          <h4>
            {`  develop
            with
            tom
            .com
            `}
          </h4>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="menu_list">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="sidebar_button">
              <Link to="/" activeClassName="user-link">
                <i>
                  <TiHomeOutline size={22} className="user-icon" />
                </i>
                <p className="user-text">HOME</p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sidebar_button">
              <Link to="/about" activeClassName="user-link">
                <i>
                  <FiUser size={22} className="user-icon" />
                </i>
                <p className="user-text">ABOUT</p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sidebar_button">
              <Link to="/skills" activeClassName="user-link">
                <i>
                  <FiSettings size={22} className="user-icon" />
                </i>
                <p className="user-text">SKILLS</p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="sidebar_button">
              <Link to="/work" activeClassName="user-link">
                <i>
                  <IoIosCode size={22} className="user-icon" />
                </i>
                <p className="user-text">MY WORK</p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="sidebar_button">
              <Link to="/contact" activeClassName="user-link">
                <i>
                  <FiMail size={22} className="user-icon" />
                </i>
                <p className="user-text">CONTACT</p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="social_list">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="skype:themcdonagh?chat">
              <i>
                <TiSocialSkypeOutline size={18} className="social-icon" />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=447712813592">
              <i>
                <FaWhatsapp size={18} className="social-icon" />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/tmcdonagh/">
              <i>
                <TiSocialLinkedin size={18} className="social-icon" />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MrTomMac">
              <i>
                <TiSocialFacebook size={18} className="social-icon" />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default Sidebar
```

My CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  background: #2e2e2e;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.sidebar h4 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

.menu_list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.social_list {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #676767;
}

.social_list a {
  color: #676767;
}

.social_list li {
  padding: 0.5vh;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu_list li {
  padding-bottom: 3vh;
}

.sidebar_button {
  /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
  /* height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px; */
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  /* font-weight: 700; */
  font-size: 0.65em;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

/* .contactbutton a,
.contactbutton a:link,
.contentbutton a:visited {
  color: #fff;
} */

.sidebar_button p {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar_button a i {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 25px;
  margin: auto;
}

.sidebar_button a:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar_button a:hover i {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.user-icon {
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

.user-text {
  color: #9a9a9a;
}

.user-link .user-icon {
  color: #97b27b;
}

.user-link .user-text {
  color: #97b27b;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icon flashing when clicked. Can I stop this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203718/icon-flashing-when-clicked-can-i-stop-this)

Comment: That question is no longer available

Comment: Hi Tom, please don't duplicate your own questions just because you have downvotes on them, that may lead to more downvotes because that's not how SO works.

Comment: Nobody explained why I had downvotes, the question is perfectly valid and clearly laid out!? People downvoted me because I hadn't' replied to a comment on the question but the comment had been edited to include a question so I got no notification (just the first notification of a comment that was a statement)

Comment: That can sometimes be puzzling yes, it happens to every user at some point. Don't take it to heart and don't delete then simply post the same question. It was probably downvoted because the code which causes the issue wasn't posted initially, you were asked to add it, so, you were potentially asking a question that no one could answer.

Comment: ok, sorry for the trouble. What does stack overflow want me to do in this scenario? Delete the question and not reask it? Or keep the question?

Comment: It is unfortunate that ended up happening. @TomMac I believe you have a legitimate question. Hopefully that is in the past now.

Comment: "Nobody explained why I had downvotes, the question is perfectly valid and clearly laid out!?" – A possible reason may be that your question lacks a [mcve]. You posted well over 200 lines of code, that is almost certainly not the absolute minimal amount of code required to reproduce the problem. I mean, there are even commented out portions of code in there, surely they are not required to reproduce the problem? Are you absolutely, completely, 100% certain that every single one of those hundreds of lines *must* be there to reproduce the problem? Not a single one can be removed?

Comment: Does it actually require 5 icons to reproduce or could it be done with one or two? I bet you can reproduce the problem in less than 20% of the code you posted.

Comment: Hi Jorg, my original (downvoted) version of the question had 1/10th of the code in it. I added much more code after it was downvoted as people may of not had enough code. The original had one icon worth of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs when you're still hovered over one of the icons after setting one of them to active. It still triggers your CSS here:

```
.sidebar_button a:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar_button a:hover i {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

We can try overriding that styling by adding classes with higher specificity now that .user-link has been added when you activate an icon:

```
.sidebar_button .user-link:hover i {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;  
}

.sidebar_button .user-link:hover p {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;  
}
```